# Minecraft LAN server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm trying to play with my bro. He can play without mods, but with mods he can't join the server. How can I resolve this? I don't want to try to find the issue in the mods. Can I find the error in the logs if the problem is caused by any mod?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Sadly any support related to modded Minecraft is off-topic here; you may have some luck looking at the logs in your launcher, if there's any stacktrace it usually indicates which class (and from that, which mod) is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, most server software's don't support mods. Unless, you run a Forge server. If players can even join with mods, they will be disabled on other server softwares. That's because the mods don't exist on the server, only on the client.

If you really want to have your friend be able to join with his mods, then run a Forge server. [Download](https://maven.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.19.2-43.1.2/forge-1.19.2-43.1.2-installer.jar) the latest installer. Then, when you run it, select "Install server". Finally, run your startup script (has `java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar SERVER_FILE_NAME.jar --nogui` on windows) in the same folder as normal.

Also, don't forget to actually **add the mods that your friend has** to the mods folder for the forge server, or else it won't work because the server still doesn't have the mods that your friend's client would.